# Is there an easy way to create search queries from objects in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm looking for a way to translate a query tree object that may look like:

```
 [Or => [And => [userid => 4,albumid =>23], And [.....] ,...]]
```

Into a laravel query

```
return $query->orWhere(function($query() { 
         return $query->where('userid', 4)
              ->where('albumid', 23);
    } )->orWhere(.....)
```

I wanted to know if something like this exists before I reinvent the wheel....

Comment: The answer will depend on what data type you have there. An array of objects, a multidimensional array, etc? Please post a `var_dump` of the actual contents of the variable that holds those query conditions definitions.

Comment: @Bogdan I'm not asking how to implement, I'm asking if someone else already did it or if laravel has some hidden way to do this. The exact object is not important - if you know of any existing implementation I will be happy to know.